# Run cucumber test and unit test in specific order

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, junit, cucumber

In my app, one cucumber test (feature) and one unit test seem to interact unexpectedly. To debug the issue I need to run them both in a specific order. So far I have tried this without success:

- run them in IDEA: I wasn't even able to run both tests at the same time. Typically with tests of the same type (or rather run by the same engine), I select several of them from the Project View and then select the Run option from the context menu. This doesn't seem to work when multiple engines (cucumber and junit-jupiter in my case) are used.
- on command line: Eventually, I came up with this

  `mvn test -Dsurefire.includeJUnit5Engines=cucumber,junit-jupiter -Dcucumber.plugin=pretty -Dcucumber.features="path-to-my-feature" -Dtest=MyTestClass`

  This indeed runs just the two tests but in a fixed order (MyTestClass first) and I'm not able to change the ordering.

Is there any way to run the cucumber test before the unit test?

Comment: Both Cucumber and JUnit Jupiter use the JUnit Platform. You could use the launcher API and run your tests programatically. https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api

Comment: That doesn't seem very convenient for an one-off action :-( But if there's no other option I will give it a try.

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje Btw do you know the mechanism behind test ordering in my mvn example? Isn't there any way (even a hacky one) how to force the order I want?

Comment: JUnit represents tests as a tree, the first layer of nodes in that tree are the test engines. These are SPI services. Their order is probably determined by the order in which their classes are loaded.

Comment: The Platform launcher API is probably the fastest way. Invoke it twice, once for JUnit once for Cucumber. In the order you want. Everything else will have you trying to understand a Rube Goldberg machine.